# Can you make Angular tell you when a directive isn't defined?

Tags: angularjs

Just spent the better part of an hour trying to figure out how to use a directive even though I've used it the exact same way before. Turns out I forgot to import the module - -;

It's very annoying since there are no errors in the console.

This reminds me of many errors I've encountered before where an error is thrown but the stack trace all points to code in angular.js even though it originated from my code.

Any recommendations on how to catch these silent/non-helpful errors? I use sublime, but I'm guessing an IDE like webstorm could catch these errors. Might motivate me to switch. Maybe some tool like angular batarang?

Comment: I find the errors in AngularJS pretty clear. Do you use the uncompressed version for development? Have you an example of an unclear error?

Comment: Using the uncompressed version of angular will help with error messages, but in general errors thrown by angular are not overly descriptive. It takes time to get used to the messages and recognize when you probably missed including a new script file or forgot to inject a module. If you are testing some new functionality double check you included and injected it first. Once you are sure angular sees it, you can debug by stepping through the code.

Comment: What I find helpful is to call `$log.log('myInjectable has loaded');` (if debugging) in the injectable. Then you can check console and see what's missing. I admit, it's a little dirty and kind of an inverse way to address your problem, but it's effective.

Comment: @Blackhole Well undefined directives for example just don't appear in the console. Also sometimes the stack trace for an error always refers to within angular.js. The actual source which originated from my code got detached so i don't know where to look. Granted these are usually "doh" errors like not injecting a module, or including a script, but they've been quite annoying the few times they occurred.

Comment: @nick exactly! I guess experience can help with making sure the basics are covered. Assume the problem is simple before assuming it's complex.

Answer (score 1):

This is a huge problem and it's hard to debug. Using the uncompressed versions doesn't really "help": it just makes it possible to get started at all (because without it you don't even get a readable error in the first place).

I've had the best luck using a good debugger like Chrome and a "break on all exceptions" trap. What I've found is that even with the minified libraries, the exception Angular throws will dump you out deep in their error-reporting call stack... but with the entire call chain preserved correctly. If you back out just a few levels and look at the local variables in those functions you can easily find these types of issues because you'll have a variable like 'module' that contains the name of the module it's not finding (for example).